# Rails 3 has_many through association unable to show or edit nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, nested-form-for

I am new to Ruby and am learning OTJ.  I have been grinding on this problem for days and have read lots of other posts regarding the has_many :through pattern.

I am using RubyMine 5.4 and ruby-1.9.3-p194 with MySQL

I have three models and I need to be able to add, remove and edit the nested relationships:

The idea is that any user can have many groups of business competitors.  A group (with the same group_id) has one target competitor and it's competition.  Each competitor is a BizEntity with it's associated attributes.  Each competitor can be a member of many different competitive groups.

I am trying to get the many to many working so I can select a user and then view/edit the users groups and related competitors.

I have run RubyMine's Inspect Code... on the models and it is clean. Yet, the Rails Model Dependency Diagram indicates (red line with ?'s at both ends) that there is an issue with the Users to BizEntity relationship.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  attr_accessible :email, :password_digest

  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  has_many :competitive_insightses, :class_name => 'CompetitiveInsights'
  has_many :biz_entitieses, :through => :competitive_insightses, :class_name => 'CompetitiveInsights', :source => :biz_entities

end

class CompetitiveInsights < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :biz_entity_id, :user_id, :group_id, :position, :target

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :biz_entities

end

class BizEntities < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :ticker

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

  has_many :competitive_insightses, :class_name => 'CompetitiveInsights'
  has_many :users, :through => :competitive_insightses, :class_name => 'CompetitiveInsights'

end
```

In my Controller the two commented lines cause the same type of errors
"undefined method `biz_entitieses' for nil:NilClass"

```
class CompetitiveInsightsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @my_companies = CompetitiveInsights.find_all_by_user_id(current_user)
    #competitive_insights = current_user.competitive_insightses
    #biz_entitieses = current_user.biz_entitieses
    if (@my_companies.nil?)
      @my_companies = CompetitiveInsights.new(current_user)
      @my_companies.save!
    end
  end
end
```

The edit.html.erb is not yet able to edit the biz_entity fields and throws the following error:

"undefined method `competitive_insight_competitive_insight_path' for #<#:0x007fc1fae4efd0>"

```
<%= form_for @my_companies do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :group_id %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :group_id %>
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :biz_entities do |biz_entity| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= biz_entity.label :ticker %><br />
      <%= biz_entity.text_field :ticker %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```